# AUTO_INCREMENT Uncontrolled Increase

Tags: mysql

I'm adding a new record using PHP to the table in the database, but the AUTO_INCREMENT value is getting ridiculously higher.

This is for a new Linux server, running MySQL 5, PHP 7.6 and Apache 2.

```
@$add_user = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO users(username, email, custom_title, avatar, message_count, is_moderator, is_admin, is_banned, is_onli`enter code here`ne, security_key) VALUES('$n_username','$n_email','$n_custom_title','$n_avatar','$n_message_count','$n_is_moderator','$n_is_admin','$n_is_banned','0','$security_key')");
```

https://i.hizliresim.com/vadEDR.png

Comment: I would say some other process it trying to insert some data but constantly failing.

Comment: There is no such version of PHP as PHP 7.6 yet

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This means that you have a process that is trying to insert records but fails - such a operation increase AUTO INCREMENT number but does not add records.

You can always pull back AUTO INCREMENT number - you can do it in PHPMyAdmin in Operations tab.

Comment: You should never pull back the AUTO INCREMENT number.

Comment: @YourCommonSense why?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the SQL instruction "TRUNCATE name_table;".